# converting array of nested structure to query

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am converting from array of structs to query, works fine, but in the case i have an array and nested structure, i am bit lost what should i modify in the function to get a query with the changed data.

I have the following code

```
<cfscript>
data = [
    {"1" :
        { i: 1, label: "One" }
    },
    {"2" :{ i: 2, label: "Two", foo: "Foo" }},
    {"3" :{ i: 3, label: "Three", bar: "Bar" }},
    {"4" :{ i: 4, label: "Four", foo: "Foo", bar: "Bar" }}
];
  
function stackoverflow(data) {
    return data.reduce(function(accumulator, element) {
        element.each(function(key) {
            if (!accumulator.keyExists(key)) {
            accumulator.addColumn(key, []);
            }
        });
        accumulator.addRow(element);
        return accumulator;
    }, QueryNew(""));
}

writeDump(data); abort;
writeDump(arrayToQuery(data));
</cfscript>
```

the above is working, if its a simple ArrayofStructs but as soon as i add a level of structure it stops working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just format the nested array to the simpler array format first and then do the reduce, like this. There are always better solutions, but all depends on the business logic that you have in you app.

```
<cfscript>
  data = [
      {"1" :{ i: 1, label: "One" }},
      {"2" :{ i: 2, label: "Two", foo: "Foo" }},
      {"3" :{ i: 3, label: "Three", bar: "Bar" }},
      {"4" :{ i: 4, label: "Four", foo: "Foo", bar: "Bar" }}
  ];
  function arrayToQuery(data) {
    return data.map(function(datum, index){
        return datum[index];
      }).reduce(
        function(accumulator, element) {
          element.each(function(key) {
            if (!accumulator.keyExists(key)) {
              accumulator.addColumn(key, []);
            }
          });
          accumulator.addRow(element);
          return accumulator;
        },
        QueryNew("")
      );
  }

  writeDump(data); 
  writeDump(arrayToQuery(data));
</cfscript>
```